# Understanding Java's varargs

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Given the `void foo(Boolean... bars)` function, the value of `bars` behaves very differently from what it apparently should be on the following function calls:

- foo(), `bars = Boolean[0]`
- foo(null), `bars = null`
- foo(null, null), `bars = Boolean[2] { null, null }`

Why does calling foo(null) yields `bars = null` instead of `Boolean[1] { null }`?
This was reproduced on Java 8.

Comment: I would hope you get a compiler warning about that. You're allowed to pass an explicit array to a varargs parameter, and for `foo(null)` it's guessing that that's what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the 3-phase approach to [determining method signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2):

1. Identify Matching Arity Methods Applicable by Strict Invocation
2. Identify Matching Arity Methods Applicable by Loose Invocation
3. Identify Methods Applicable by Variable Arity Invocation

`foo(null)` is matched in phase 1, because a single null argument is allowable for a method accepting a `Boolean[]`, because you can cast `null` to `Boolean[]` (or, indeed, any reference type).

`foo(null, null)` is matched in phase 3, because that's when variable arity methods are matched. Assuming you don't have a 2-arg overload of `foo`, it couldn't be matched before that, because a matching method would require two arguments.